# Mini rail gun to build at home

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

at around 2.20 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dm30ckh-pW8&ab_channel=CSIRO) the woman says that if it doesn't work, you should try and turn the magnet around. I've tried it and the magnets do need to be facing each other with the same pole or else it won't work. Why exactly is that? And why does she use magnets at all? Isn't the magnetic field used for the acceleration the one from the alu foil? Or is it really the magnetic field from the magnets? If so, why does it make such a big difference if you turn one magnet around? Is it because the field looks like in my crappy graphic here?

[image: field]

Answer (score 0):

Magnets have a positive and a negative, the electric charge has a positive and a negative. Positive attracts negative, positive repels positive. By putting an electric charge in the foil, it is repelling the magnet and causing it to roll. If the magnet was the wrong way around nothing would happen. Likewise, you could also switch where you have the positive and where you have negative.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand at all what you are saying. Do you mean that magnetic north poles (or south) are repulsed by electrons? That sounds odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly is that? Because this works off of magnetic repulsion. If they are not facing the same direction the repulsion of one will be canceled by the pull of the other.
And why does she use magnets at all? Because it works by creating a magnetic field around the aluminum which repels the permanent magnets.
Isn't the magnetic field used for the acceleration the one from the alu foil? Both fields are used, they repel each other.  Or is it really the magnetic field from the magnets? Both fields are used, they repel each other.  Is it because the field looks like in my crappy graphic here? Your graphic is too crappy to understand, but no.

Comment: Why does it work off repulsion? I thought the principle here was the Lorentz Force: Electrons with velocity v travel through the bridge and perpendicular to that there is a magnetic field caused by the current on the alu foil. In conclusion there is a force on the electrons perpendicular on both which causes the stick to roll.

Comment: It does work off of Lorentz Force, Lorentz Force is a combination of electric and magnetic force.

Comment: Now that doesn't make sense to me:
1. Does ist work because the magnets get repelled by the field of the foil?
2. Or does it work because the Lorentz Force acts on the electrons in the bridge?
It can't be both.

Comment: It is in fact both. However, the more contributing factor is the magnetic field generated by the rails is repelling the magnetic field generated by the wire and the added permanent magnets.

Comment: I think I'm having trouble explaining properly. Try this: http://sciphile.org/lessons/classroom-rail-gun